# Django form not visible after redirect

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to make django form to appear after user is logged in and authenticated but the form just does not appear on the page here is my code. I'm  stuck on this for few days now and any help would be huge help

Views.py form code

```
def prasymas(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']

  form = Prasymas(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
  context ={
    'form':form
  }
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

urls.py code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  # /
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  # TEMPORARY
  path('signin', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
  path('signout', views.sign_out, name='signout'),
  path('callback', views.callback, name='callback'),
  path('prasymas', views.home, name='prasymas'),
 ]
```

template.py code

```
  {% extends "loginas/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center"></h1>
  <p class="d-flex justify-content-center"></p>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h4>Sveiki {{ user.firstname }} {{user.surname}}     
    </h4>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button class="btn btn-secondary">POST</button>
    </form>
  {% else %}<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="{% url 'signin' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-large ">Prisijungti</a>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
 
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your view, you're not passing the context to your template so it's like it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

From your urls.py it looks like the `prasymas` function in views.py is not being called.

Try making the following change to your urls.py file to include a call to the `prasymas` function.

Note: the line  `path('prasymas', views.prasymas, name='prasymas'),` now points to `views.prasymas` not home. This means the path /prasymas will now render your form.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  # /
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  # TEMPORARY
  path('signin', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
  path('signout', views.sign_out, name='signout'),
  path('callback', views.callback, name='callback'),
  path('prasymas', views.prasymas, name='prasymas'),
 ]
```

Comment: Tried to put views.home in url still the same